# Passando dados com a propriedade data (Routes) e State (Navigate)

Tags: angular

Depois de um clique no botão, preciso ir pra uma outra rota. E setar o filtro pra que retorne um certo dado. Não queria utilizar o queryParams, nem params para não zoar o filtro.

Utilizo o método navigate. Preciso setar um valor na propriedade data da rota. Tem como? Se não for possível, a partir do angular 7 o segundo parâmetro do método navigate pode ser um objeto “state” e passar um valor por ele e você pode recuperar esse dado em outro componente. Mas como setar um valor nele, em outro componente?